# How to use NHibernate DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn and References for the same column

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

## The Setup

I am using [FluentNHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org) 1.4.0 for my NHibernate 3.3.3-SP1 mappings in a .NET4.0 library. I'm using the "table-per-inheritance" approach for my type hierarchy as follows:

```sql
-- Different process types potentially use 
-- different types of reference values
CREATE TABLE ProcessTypes
(Id INT PRIMARY KEY)

-- Contains reference values for value comparisons
CREATE TABLE ProcessReferenceValues
(Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
 ProcessTypeId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ProcessTypes(Id),
 FloatReferencesValue FLOAT NULL,
 IntReferenceValue INT NULL)
```

```cs
// POCOs

class ProcessReferenceValues
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcessTypes ProcessType { get; set; }
    public virtual float? FloatReferenceValue { get; set; }
    public virtual int? IntReferenceValue { get; set; }
}

class IntProcessReferenceValues : ProcessReferenceValues { }

class FloatProcessReferenceValues : ProcessReferenceValues { }

enum ProcessTypeName : int
{
    IntProcess = 1,
    FloatProcess = 2
}

class ProcessTypes
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcessTypeName Name { get; set; }
}

// FluentNHibernate Mappings

class ProcessReferenceValuesMap 
    : FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap<ProcessReferenceValues>
{
    public ProcessReferenceValuesMap()
    {
        string processTypeId = "ProcessTypeId";

        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.Map(x => x.FloatReferenceValue).Nullable();
        this.Map(x => x.IntReferenceValue).Nullable();

        // Here is the tricky bit
        this.References(x => x.ProcessType, processTypeId);
        this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn(processTypeId);
    }
}

class IntProcessReferenceValuesMap 
    : FluentNHibernate.Mapping.SubclassMap<IntProcessReferenceValues>
{
    public IntProcessReferenceValuesMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue((int)ProcessTypeName.IntProcess);
    }
}

class FloatProcessReferenceValuesMap 
    : FluentNHibernate.Mapping.SubclassMap<FloatProcessReferenceValues>
{
    public FloatProcessReferenceValuesMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue((int)ProcessTypeName.FloatProcess);
    }
}

class ProcessPeriodTypesMap : FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap<ProcessPeriodTypes>
{
    public ProcessPeriodTypesMap()
    {
        this.ReadOnly();
        this.Id(x => x.Id, "id");
        this.Map(x => x.Name, "id").ReadOnly().CustomType<PeriodTypeName>();
    }
}
```

## The Problem

While reading from the database works like a charm - the appropriate sub classes are selected correctly - saving a new process reference value gives me an exception:

```cs
// Reading

var processType =
   (from type in session.Query<ProcessTypes>()
    where type.Name == ProcessTypeName.IntProcess
    select type).FirstOrDefault(); // OK, finds the IntProcess

var referenceValues =
   (from val in session.Query<ProcessReferenceValues>()
    select val).ToList(); // OK, finds the appropriate subclasses
```

```cs
// Inserting

var processType = new ProcessTypes
{
    Id = (int)ProcessTypeName.IntProcess
};

var referenceValue = new ProcessReferenceValues
{
    FloatReferenceValue = 0.7f,
    IntReferenceValue = null,
    ProcessType = processType // Needs the appropriate ProcessType
};
session.Save(referenceValue); // <- BOOM!
```

```
Error dehydrating property value for ProcessReferenceValues.ProcessType

Invalid Index 2 for OleDbParameterCollection with Count=2.
    bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection.RangeCheck(Int32 index)
    bei System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection.GetParameter(Int32 index)
    bei System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
    bei NHibernate.Type.Int32Type.Set(IDbCommand rs, Object value, Int32 index) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Type\Int32Type.cs:Zeile 60.
    bei NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, Object value, Int32 index) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Type\NullableType.cs:Zeile 182.
    bei NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Type\NullableType.cs:Zeile 122.
    bei NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value, Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Type\ManyToOneType.cs:Zeile 50.
    bei NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement, ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:Zeile 2410.
```

As always in hard times I summoned the gooragle and the problem seems to be that the `this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn(processTypeId)` adds a conflict with the `this.References(x => x.ProcessType, processTypeId)` mapping. When I remove the former the insert is successful but I want the subclass mapping AND I also need to be able to set the `ProcessReferenceValues.ProcessType` when adding new instances of `ProcessReferenceValues` to distinguish the subclasses.

## The Question

Is it possible to discriminate subclasses on a column and at the same time referencing that same column on the same type?

Help very much appreciated, there's got to be a way to do this ...

*thx in advance!*

Comment: is the extra table really nessesary, won't the column `int referencetype` in ProcessReference table suffice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

classes and mappings without the problem

// POCOs

```
class ProcessValue
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract ProcessValueType Type { get; }
}

class IntProcessValue : ProcessValue
{
    public virtual int? Value { get; set; }
    public override ProcessValueType Type { get { return ProcessValueType.Int; } }
}

class FloatProcessValue : ProcessValue
{
    public virtual float? Value { get; set; }
    public override ProcessValueType Type { get { return ProcessValueType.Float; } }
}

enum ProcessValueType : int
{
    Int = 1,
    Float = 2
}
```

// FluentNHibernate Mappings

```
class ProcessValueMap  : ClassMap<ProcessValue>
{
    public ProcessValueMap()
    {
        string processTypeId = "ProcessValueTypeId";

        Id(x => x.Id);

        // just so you can query by type enum also. Querying by clr Type is already implemented
        Map(x => x.Type, processTypeId).CustomType<ProcessValueType>().ReadOnly().Access.None();
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn(processTypeId);
    }
}

class IntProcessValueMap  : SubclassMap<IntProcessValue>
{
    public IntProcessValueMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Value).Nullable();

        DiscriminatorValue((int)ProcessValueType.Int);
    }
}

class FloatProcessValueMap  : SubclassMap<FloatProcessValue>
{
    public FloatProcessValueMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Value).Nullable();

        DiscriminatorValue((int)ProcessValueType.Float);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise, the problem is that I need the `ProcessValueType` to be an entity inside the database not just an enum value in my code

Comment: I assume they are static with known ids otherwise you would not have defined an enum for their names. Since you do not need it as entity in your code the above is fine to save and load them. Creating the table with schema export can be done with an `IAuxiliaryObject` or a fake mapping

Comment: I finally went with your proposed solution, thanks! I had to make adjustments getting it to work with NHibernate 3.3.3: getter-only properties are no longer supported so I had to add a protected setter for the `ProcessValueType` properties - this seems stupid but I haven't found any sane workaround to enable the querying by enum value functionality

Comment: i forgot `.Access.None()` there. Plz try it with that and without the protected setter

Comment: This works although I thought that NHibernate wouldn't know about the value with this access mode ... it seems like the `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn` takes care of this. Thanks again, this is much cleaner :-)